# Can an Electron window use windows authentication to login to SSO?

Tags: node.js, electron, windows-authentication

I have a very early stage electron application that we are using for a proof of concept.
I am using `mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com');` in my file to open the window to our internal application.

The issue I am facing is that this website uses SSO for authentication.

In a Chrome / IE Browser, the SSO happens automatically as it is utilizing Windows authentication.

Is it possible to tell the electron browser window that is being created to use this authentication as well?

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: winState.width,
        height: winState.height,
        minWidth: 992,
        minHeight: 500,
        x: winState.x,
        y: winState.y
    });

    // Set our menu
    setMenu();

    // Load main window that uses SSO
    // When using Chrome or IE, windows authentication passes this without needing to prompt for the credentials.
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `session.allowNTLMCredentialsForDomains('example.com')`
This will allow the BrowserWindow to send NTLM credentials for the given domain(s). It also supports wildcards using * read more about it here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session#sesallowntlmcredentialsfordomainsdomains

```
// add this on top
const { session } = require('electron');
session.defaultSession.allowNTLMCredentialsForDomains('example.com')

// your code here  
...
```

Comment: Does this work only on Windows ?